# How to partition by year of a varchar type field

Tags: postgresql

I am learning postgresql, I have a source file, with a field in varchar type, the value of it is like this:

```
20190625
20190626
20190627
20190628
20190629
20190630
```

Now I want to partition by the first characters of this field, that means, partition by year,

I try to do it like this:

```
partition by range(substr(str, 1,4));
```

But that does not work, I want to partition by year. For example if there are 10 years then create 10 partitions, if there are 20 years, then 20 partitions. The number of partitions are not fixed, how to do that?

Comment: Unrelated, but: why on earth are you storing DATE values in a `varchar` column? That is a really bad idea to begin with

Comment: that's requested by customer,

Comment: Just once I would like those people responsible for stupid decisions like that to also be forced to work with that.... - you have my sympathy.

Comment: the version is 11.4

Comment: yes, one partition for every year,

Comment: `substr(str, 1,4)` is correct, so if *it does not work* then the way you use it is wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunately "those people responsible for stupid decisions" are not the customers but IT just being too lazy to use conversions routines so the customer sees what they want in the business operation while the DB contains what it should. It is an analysis failure by IT/Development. So those making stupid decisions are the ones having to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `date` would have been a better data type, but since the dates are at least in the form “year-month-day” simple range partitioning on the column should do:

```
CREATE TABLE data (...)
PARTITION BY RANGE (str);

CREATE TABLE data_2019
PARTITION OF data FOR VALUES FROM ('20190101') TO ('20200101');
```

This is because in this format the date order, the numeric order and the string order are identical.

Make sure to add `COLLATE "C"` to the column definition to make the string comparisons as cheap as possible.

I'd add a check constraint to ascertain that the data always have this format.